# REGEXP_SUBSTR to split comma separated values into rows not working

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table structure that contains data in column in comma separated values. I want to split these values into rows.

The data in table is something like this

```
MANUFACTURER_PART_NUMBER|MANUFACTURER_NAME        |TEST_PLAN           |ATTACHED_SUPPLIER_DOCUMENT |ATTACHED_LOGITECH_REPORT|
------------------------|-------------------------|--------------------|---------------------------|------------------------|
001059-0000             |CHENGDA                  |268452,268453       |268456,268457,268459,268460|268465                  |
001059-0000             |SHANGHAI MARRISON CO.,LTD|                    |268458,268462              |                        |
001059-0000             |SUZHOU SHARETECH         |                    |                           |                        |
001059-0000             |SYSTRON                  |268451,268452,268453|268456,268457,268459,268460|268465,268466           |
```

I have tried this query but it is not behaving well not sure the reason

```
WITH CTE AS(
SELECT DISTINCT 
MP.PART_NUMBER MANUFACTURER_PART_NUMBER, M.NAME MANUFACTURER_NAME, 
RTRIM(LTRIM(PG3.MULTILIST31, ','), ',') TEST_PLAN,
RTRIM(LTRIM(PG3.MULTILIST32, ','), ',') ATTACHED_SUPPLIER_DOCUMENT,
RTRIM(LTRIM(PG3.MULTILIST33, ','), ',') ATTACHED_LOGITECH_REPORT
FROM MANU_PARTS MP
INNER JOIN MANUFACTURERS M ON M.ID = MP.MANU_ID 
LEFT JOIN PAGE_TWO PG2 ON PG2.ID = MP.ID
LEFT JOIN PAGE_THREE PG3 ON PG3.ID = MP.ID

WHERE PART_NUMBER = '001059-0000'
)

SELECT DISTINCT 
MANUFACTURER_PART_NUMBER, MANUFACTURER_NAME, 
REGEXP_SUBSTR(TEST_PLAN, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) TEST_PLAN, 
REGEXP_SUBSTR(ATTACHED_SUPPLIER_DOCUMENT, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) ATTACHED_SUPPLIER_DOCUMENT, 
REGEXP_SUBSTR(ATTACHED_LOGITECH_REPORT, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) ATTACHED_LOGITECH_REPORT
FROM CTE 
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(NVL(NVL(TEST_PLAN, ATTACHED_SUPPLIER_DOCUMENT), ATTACHED_LOGITECH_REPORT), '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY MANUFACTURER_NAME
```

It should be giving the following output which is required too

```
MANUFACTURER_PART_NUMBER|MANUFACTURER_NAME        |TEST_PLAN|ATTACHED_SUPPLIER_DOCUMENT|ATTACHED_LOGITECH_REPORT|
------------------------|-------------------------|---------|--------------------------|------------------------|
001059-0000             |CHENGDA                  |268452   |268456                    |268465                  |
001059-0000             |CHENGDA                  |268453   |268457                    |                        |
001059-0000             |CHENGDA                  |         |268459                    |                        |
001059-0000             |CHENGDA                  |         |268460                    |                        |
001059-0000             |SHANGHAI MARRISON CO.,LTD|         |268458                    |                        |
001059-0000             |SHANGHAI MARRISON CO.,LTD|         |268462                    |                        |
001059-0000             |SUZHOU SHARETECH         |         |                          |                        |
001059-0000             |SYSTRON                  |268451   |268456                    |268465                  |
001059-0000             |SYSTRON                  |268452   |268457                    |268466                  |
001059-0000             |SYSTRON                  |268453   |268459                    |                        |
001059-0000             |SYSTRON                  |         |268460                    |                        |
```

But instead it is giving this out put and missing 2 rows or values for 1st `CHENGDA` and last 1 row of `SYSTRON`

```
MANUFACTURER_PART_NUMBER|MANUFACTURER_NAME        |TEST_PLAN|ATTACHED_SUPPLIER_DOCUMENT|ATTACHED_LOGITECH_REPORT|
------------------------|-------------------------|---------|--------------------------|------------------------|
001059-0000             |CHENGDA                  |268452   |268456                    |268465                  |
001059-0000             |CHENGDA                  |268453   |268457                    |                        |
001059-0000             |SHANGHAI MARRISON CO.,LTD|         |268458                    |                        |
001059-0000             |SHANGHAI MARRISON CO.,LTD|         |268462                    |                        |
001059-0000             |SUZHOU SHARETECH         |         |                          |                        |
001059-0000             |SYSTRON                  |268451   |268456                    |268465                  |
001059-0000             |SYSTRON                  |268452   |268457                    |268466                  |
001059-0000             |SYSTRON                  |268453   |268459                    |                        |
```

The reason which I found out is when I swap the position of `Test Plan` and `Attached Supplier Document` in Connect By clause which probably is because of number of values in both columns. But this should no be happening because what if Test Plan had more values in any case ?

Hope someone could help.

(Before marking this question duplicate please do ask if it already has an answer or not because that query did not work)

Comment: Fix your data model!  Don't store multiple values in strings!  Don't store numbers in strings!  Declare foreign key relationships!

Comment: The result you're after implies there is a relationship between, say,  test plan 268453 and supplier document 268457, just by those both being the second element in their lists. That seems a rather arbitrary way to associate things - it's dodgy even when the lists always have the same number of elements, but when they vary how do you know what is supposed to be linked to what? (Or do they have the same number, and your ltrim/rtrim are removing that potential pseudo-link?)

Comment: @GordonLinoff Can't really change the data model. It's Oracle's Agile database.

Comment: Might be simpler to do this through API calls - are you supposed to access the Agile database directly for this sort of thing?

Comment: @AlexPoole I have access to the database I just have to extract the data in particular format.

Comment: @MuhammadAsim - you've put a bounty on this but you haven't said what is wrong with the existing answer (which happens to be mine, but that's not the point). If that doesn't do what you need then comment on that answer explaining why, and if necessary add further details to your question.

Comment: @AlexPoole Your query is taking so much time to execute. You won't believe but it's been more than 2 hours and still executing.

Comment: @AlexPoole Though I have got the result and shared answer too. Hope you can look into it and provide your feedback as well

Comment: Looking at the "data model" and the requirements, I can imagine _any_ correct answer will be slow!

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in comments, your data model isn't ideal, and you shouldn't be storing lists of values in strings. Assuming you're stuck with that, your problem is that the lists have different numbers of elements, so the depth can be different for each, leading to different limits on `level`; and trying to guess which to base it on is going to be a problem, as you've already realised.

You could possibly try to figure out which value to use for each ID using `regexp_count` and `greatest` but that's going to be tricky with multiple rows to deal with as well. (The `distinct` is an indication that you already have an issue there...)

Another approach is to split up each list individually and then try to associate matching elements - though that seems fairly arbitrary in itself. This seems to get the result you want though:

```
select mp.part_number,
  m.name,
  t.value31,
  t.value32,
  t.value33
from manu_parts mp
join manufacturers m
on m.id = mp.manu_id
left join (
  select coalesce(t31.id, t32.id, t33.id) as id,
    coalesce(t31.lvl, t32.lvl, t33.lvl) as lvl,
    t31.value as value31,
    t32.value as value32,
    t33.value as value33
  from 
  (
    select id, level as lvl,
      regexp_substr(multilist31, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, level, null, 1) as value
    from page_three
    connect by id = prior id
    and prior dbms_random.value is not null
    and level < regexp_count(multilist31, '(.*?)(,|$)')
  ) t31
  full outer join (
    select id, level as lvl,
      regexp_substr(multilist32, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, level, null, 1) as value
    from page_three
    connect by id = prior id
    and prior dbms_random.value is not null
    and level < regexp_count(multilist32, '(.*?)(,|$)')
  ) t32 
  on t32.id = t31.id and t32.lvl = t31.lvl
  full outer join (
    select id, level as lvl,
      regexp_substr(multilist33, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, level, null, 1) as value
    from page_three
    connect by id = prior id
    and prior dbms_random.value is not null
    and level < regexp_count(multilist33, '(.*?)(,|$)')
  ) t33
  on (t33.id = t32.id and t33.lvl = t32.lvl)
  or (t33.id = t31.id and t33.lvl = t31.lvl)
) t on t.id = mp.id
where part_number = '001059-0000'
order by part_number, name, lvl;
```

```
PART_NUMBER NAME                      VALUE31    VALUE32    VALUE33   
----------- ------------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
001059-0000 CHENGDA                   268452     268456     268465    
001059-0000 CHENGDA                   268453     268457               
001059-0000 CHENGDA                              268459               
001059-0000 CHENGDA                              268460               
001059-0000 SHANGHAI MARRISON CO.,LTD            268458               
001059-0000 SHANGHAI MARRISON CO.,LTD            268462               
001059-0000 SUZHOU SHARETECH                                          
001059-0000 SYSTRON                   268451     268456     268465    
001059-0000 SYSTRON                   268452     268457     268466    
001059-0000 SYSTRON                   268453     268459               
001059-0000 SYSTRON                              268460               

11 rows selected.
```

Each subquery like:

```
  (
    select id, level as lvl,
      regexp_substr(multilist31, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, level, null, 1) as value
    from page_three
    connect by id = prior id
    and prior dbms_random.value is not null
    and level < regexp_count(multilist31, '(.*?)(,|$)')
  ) t31
```

splits a single column from that table, preserving the ID to join against later, and the level to associate with the other columns for that ID. The three of those are then outer joined together; and the result of *that* is joined to the main table.

The performance might be horrible, but if you're filtering on a single part number then that *might* be pushed into the subqueries so it doesn't do more work than needed.

You could also look at recursive subquery factoring instead of hierarchical queries, or possibly correlated subqueries with collections, but they will all have their own issues. That's what happens when you have to work around a bad data model.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE AS(
SELECT DISTINCT 
MP.PART_NUMBER MANUFACTURER_PART_NUMBER, M.NAME MANUFACTURER_NAME, 
RTRIM(LTRIM(PG3.MULTILIST31, ','), ',') TEST_PLAN, 
RTRIM(LTRIM(PG3.MULTILIST32, ','), ',') ATTACHED_SUPPLIER_DOCUMENT, 
RTRIM(LTRIM(PG3.MULTILIST33, ','), ',') ATTACHED_LOGITECH_REPORT  
FROM MANU_PARTS MP
INNER JOIN MANUFACTURERS M ON M.ID = MP.MANU_ID 
LEFT JOIN PAGE_TWO PG2 ON PG2.ID = MP.ID
LEFT JOIN PAGE_THREE PG3 ON PG3.ID = MP.ID
WHERE PART_NUMBER = '001059-0000'
)
SELECT MANUFACTURER_PART_NUMBER, MANUFACTURER_NAME, 
REGEXP_SUBSTR(TEST_PLAN, '[^,]+', 1, column_value) TEST_PLAN, 
REGEXP_SUBSTR(ATTACHED_SUPPLIER_DOCUMENT, '[^,]+', 1, column_value) ATTACHED_SUPPLIER_DOCUMENT,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(ATTACHED_LOGITECH_REPORT, '[^,]+', 1, column_value) ATTACHED_LOGITECH_REPORT

FROM CTE 
CROSS JOIN TABLE(CAST(MULTISET(SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= GREATEST(REGEXP_COUNT(NVL(ATTACHED_LOGITECH_REPORT, 0), ','), REGEXP_COUNT(NVL(TEST_PLAN, 0), ','), REGEXP_COUNT(NVL(ATTACHED_SUPPLIER_DOCUMENT, 0), ','))+1 
) AS sys.odcinumberlist))
```

I have managed to get the desired result by checking the maximum count of the column and allocating that to each item.

Here is the output.

```
MANUFACTURER_PART_NUMBER|MANUFACTURER_NAME        |TEST_PLAN|ATTACHED_SUPPLIER_DOCUMENT|ATTACHED_LOGITECH_REPORT|
------------------------|-------------------------|---------|--------------------------|------------------------|
001059-0000             |CHENGDA                  |268452   |268456                    |268465                  |
001059-0000             |CHENGDA                  |268453   |268457                    |                        |
001059-0000             |CHENGDA                  |         |268459                    |                        |
001059-0000             |CHENGDA                  |         |268460                    |                        |
001059-0000             |SYSTRON                  |268451   |268456                    |268465                  |
001059-0000             |SYSTRON                  |268452   |268457                    |268466                  |
001059-0000             |SYSTRON                  |268453   |268459                    |                        |
001059-0000             |SYSTRON                  |         |268460                    |                        |
001059-0000             |SUZHOU SHARETECH         |         |                          |                        |
001059-0000             |SHANGHAI MARRISON CO.,LTD|         |268458                    |                        |
001059-0000             |SHANGHAI MARRISON CO.,LTD|         |268462                    |                        |
```